# SwiftyJSON Populate TableView - Empty Cells

Tags: json, swift, parsing, tableview

I'm managed to parse some JSON in Swift, and I'm struggling a little. I need to extract the 'title' string from the "Event" property. I've got "Hasta" & "Location", which is good for me (beginner). So, now I'm trying to populate a tableview with these 3 properties. So far, the tableview is empty, and isn't display my information. Any help? Please bear in mind I'm a relative beginner- so careful explanation would be welcome. I've been using SwiftyJSON to parse the JSON. I've given my code explanatory markers. For reference I have a variable = var TableData = String.

```
    let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            if let _ = data {
                do {
                    let jsonString = try NSString.init(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                    // Create JSON object from data
                    let json = JSON(data: jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!)

                    // Check if array for key "collection2" exists
                    if let collection2 = json["results"]["collection2"].array {
                        // Create JSON array from it and loop for each object

                        for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in JSON(collection2) {
                            // Check if dictionary for key "Event" exists
                            if let event = subJson["Event"].dictionary {
                                print(event)
                            }

                            // Check if string for key "Hasta" exists
                            if let hasta = subJson["Hasta"].string {
                                self.TableData.append(hasta)
                                //print(hasta)
                            }

                            // Check if string for key "Location" exists
                            if let location = subJson["Location"].string {
                                self.TableData.append(location)
                                //print(location)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("In catch block")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to populate a table (below). I realize I'd need to make a custom cell with 3 labels. But for now, is it possible just to populate the tableview with any of the 3, just to see whether it work.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return self.TableData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.TableData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: so, any thoughts? :)

Comment: Removed extravagant amounts of newlines for readability

Comment: Thanks... But anybody care to help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some unnecessary things here. At first you setup a task to download data from url. In completion block, after the request is finished, you create a string with `contentsOfURL`, which calls the same request again and turns the response to string. Then you create NSData from the string and pass it to `JSON()` to parse the JSON string. But you already have the data available in the completion block:

```
session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
```

So you can just turn this:

```
let jsonString = try NSString.init(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let json = JSON(data: jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!)
```

into this:

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
```

But this doesn't answer you question yet. When you're done storing data into your `TableData`, you have to refresh the TableView. So at the end of the completion block try calling

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

This is how this should work (not tested):

```
let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        if data != nil {
            // Create JSON object from data
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            // Check if array for key "collection2" exists
            if let collection2 = json["results"]["collection2"].array {
                // Create JSON array from it and loop for each object
                for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in JSON(collection2) {
                    var data: [String : Any] = [String : Any]()

                    // Check if dictionary for key "Event" exists
                    if let event = subJson["Event"].dictionary {
                        data["event"] = event
                    }
                    // Check if string for key "Hasta" exists
                    if let hasta = subJson["Hasta"].string {
                        data["hasta"] = hasta
                    }
                    // Check if string for key "Location" exists
                    if let location = subJson["Location"].string {
                        data["location"] = location
                    }

                    self.TableData.append(data)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Excellent haluzak! But I get an error now..."'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block". Any help?

Comment: Well now you don't have any `try` in the do/try/catch block, so catch never gets called because you don't ever "try" anything. I didn't notice that, sorry. You can just remove the do/catch block as well, see the edited answer.

Comment: excellent thanks a lot!! :) Can I change the order, so they print in another order?

Comment: I now have three textlabels... 'textLabel1" "textLabel1" & "textLabel3". Would would a print the info for each string... "Event", "Hasta" & "Location" in each? Thanks

Comment: well what kind of object is a TableData? I guess a simple array? It would probably be better to store dictionaries in that array and then in `cellForRow` you would obtain that dictionary and populate labels.

Comment: Could you please explain how I might go about that? :D

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to store data, I'm sure you'll figure out how to show them in labels ;)

Comment: Why can't everyone be as helpful as you? haha.. I get an error "cannot assign a value of type '[String: JSON]' to a value of type AnyObject?'

Comment: Well that depends what a JSON is, just try to change [String : AnyObject] to [String : JSON].

Comment: Thanks a lot, hope I'm not a pain. I tend to learn by knowing the 'solution' and then working backwards to see how one got there... so it's important to 'get there' first (which I can't do alone obv haha)... Changing that returns..."Cannot assign a value of type "String" to a value of type 'JSON?'' (with the "data["hasta"] = hasta")

Comment: OK... I got it to work now. Thanks a lot... Now to figure out the label part :) Thanks man!

Comment: OK.. i think I'll need some help.. I can't see the wood for the trees... and I doubt I'll find anyone later to help me who understands what I want to do as well as you do right now. If you could help, I'd really appreciate it haluzak? :)

Comment: Try replacing `AnyObject` with `Any` in data dictionary, since hasta and location are strings and event is a dictionary (JSON).

Comment: I found a workaround by adding an '["Event"]["text"]' if let... I can get the info to print by using:                                                         cell.textLabel1?.text = self.TableData[3]
cell.textLabel2?.text = self.TableData[4]
cell.textLabel3?.text = self.TableData[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   But this just repeats the first line of JSON data.. There needs to be some kind of indexPath code? help!

Comment: try to look at what you're storing in TableData and it should be pretty obvious, maybe try to print whole TableData and I'm sure you'll figure it out ;)

Comment: Ah, I'm struggling still haha... I'm storing an array of strings? I can't figure it out man haha

Comment: You store data like this: `var data: [String : Any] = [String : Any]()` `self.TableData.append(data)`. In TableData you store type [String : Any], which is a dictionary. So when you want to fetch data from TableData you get it like this: `let data = self.TableData[indexPath.row]` `hastaLabel.text = data["hasta"]`

Comment: Thanks you very much, haluzak. But, does that mean I add: cell.textLabel1?.text = self.TableData.append(data)? Because that returns an error?

Comment: No, see edited comment. `let data = self.TableData[indexPath.row]`   `cell.textLabel1?.text = data["hasta"]`

Comment: So I add both, right? Then it returns, for the "cell.textLabel1?.text" line: Cannot subscript a value of type String with an index of type String? Sorry for the annoyance.  But, if I learn the correct answer now, I can figure it out working backward :) This line: self.TableData.append(data), returns an error too.